# File upload implementation using RichFaces 4.3.7

Tags: jsf, file-upload, richfaces

I am trying to add a file upload component in my application, I used Tomahawk, but it doesn't work with ajax which is essential in my case. So I used RichFaces, I add these jars to my lib folder :

1. richfaces-core-api-4.3.7.Final.jar
2. richfaces-core-impl-4.3.7.Final.jar
3. richfaces-components-api-4.3.7.Final.jar
4. richfaces-components-ui-4.3.7.Final.jar

   then I added this tag to my index.xhtml

   `<rich:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{createListBean.listner}"
               maxFilesQuantity="1" id="file" immediateUpload="false"
               acceptedTypes=".xls,.xlsx,.csv" allowFlash="false">
         <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" render=":contact-form:error_mess :contact form:records-form-table" />
   </rich:fileUpload>`

So my problem is there is an iframe appeared and also I can't find the upload button , and the css looks awful , all I need is an upload file input text and a button to upload with my own css on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a problem with resources, can you compare with [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try considering `Primefaces` [Like this](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/fileUploadHome.jsf) as it is Ajax enabled and very stable except IE 7. you can find many different file uploader like basic, multi, drag n drop, file filter, size limit

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I can't use primefaces, is there any way to use richfaces or even icefaces with ajax ?

Comment: This is not a valid answer, a suggestion can be a comment if the suggestion is "somehow" helped you can post it as an answer. Now @YaraMousa if you can't use primefaces why did you accept the answer, and asked another one ?

Comment: He didn't know that this is not applicable in my case, I just want help in this problem .

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether the component using iframe or new XMLHttpRequest extension FormData object to implement ajax functionality. But when you add component to your page, it will show a component like in this page [Richfaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky). At first upload button is not visible, but when you select some files to upload, it will be visible automatically.